# Font Awesome 4.0.0 Missing Icons

Tags: font-awesome

Is it just me or there are actually icons in FontAwesome 3.x.x that are missing from FontAwesome 4.0.0? If so, this definitely makes FontAwesome much less awesome for me...

For example, I can't seem to find the equivalent to `icon-remove` (there is no `fa-remove`, or `fa-delete` as far as I can tell).

Having to rename all icon references in my application is annoying enough. Not being able to reproduce what was possible in 3.0 is really, really bad.

Not being able to access v3.x cheatsheet and other documentation any more: unacceptable!

Comment: What about `fa-times`?

Comment: @Michał Close, but not the same icon as before.

Comment: same ;) I've used it so many **times** in v3.2.1...

Comment: @Michał Duh! You are right, it *is* the same. I was getting confused by our custom glyph. So I take it back: the font is still **Awesome**. :-)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`icon-remove` is renamed to `fa-times` in v4.0.0.

Quick comparison:

- [old one](http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/remove/)
- [new one](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/times/)

Note that some icons that seem to be missing can be easily constructed using [stacking options](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) - I have created [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/VkKAH/) for `icon-remove-sign` replaced by `fa-times` stacked on `fa-circle`.

Note: As @VaclavElias pointed out, `icon-remove-sign` is now `fa-times-circle`. The above is just an example of stacking.

Comment: In case of icon-remove-sign, use this, built in Font Awesome 4.0 <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>

Comment: @VaclavElias, thanks for pointing that out! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome, also was looking for this icon and found it through other resources so this should help others :)

Comment: There is an `fa-edit` alias to `fa-pencil-square-o`. Shouldn't there be an alias of `fa-remove` to `fa-times`? One (`fa-times`) is its _denotative_ name, the other (`fa-remove`) would be one of its _connotative_ names.

Answer (score 6):

The 4.0.0 release has the same icons as 3.2.1, but the naming conventions and many of the individual icon names have been changed.

You can view a list of changes that Geremia Taglialatela compiled over on the Github wiki for Font Awesome:

- [Upgrading from 3.2.1 to 4](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4)

Also, you can still access the documentation for 3.2.1 [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/)

Comment: The upgrading link is what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little LESS file that allows the integration of the old names into the new FontAwesome version.
For this is took the list Michał Rybak posted: [Upgrading from 3.2.1 to 4.0](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4)

If anyone is interested in downloading, you can find it on Github: [Download v3 to v4 FontAwesome Integration](https://github.com/code-flow/FontAwesome-v3-Icons-in-v4)

Answer (score 1):

**--EDITED--**

[Michal Rybak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995170/michal-rybak) is actually spot on. You should submit that as an answer. The icon looks exactly the same. Can't believe I missed that.

Though I'd like to point out, in the FA site it says, if you know what it looks like you know the class name in 4.0, It think it looks like a cross, or X. I would have never guessed  "times"

**--ORIGINAL--**

I came here looking for fa-remove as well! That's disappointing. Now it looks like I have to revert back to a previous version after having migrated 2/3rd of my app to the new version.

To answer your point about documentation: The old version can be accessed here:

http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/

I found the link while browsing through their site and stumbled upon their notice about no IE7 compatibility.

This definitely needs to be linked (atleast) in the footer

Comment: Thanks for the 3.2.1 link, although in the meantime I bit the bullet and converted to 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the Wikipedia icon is still missing on 4.0 and even 4.3
but this workaround worked for me:

```
.fa-wikipedia:before { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-weight: 400; 
content: "VV"; letter-spacing:-0.45em; margin-right:0.5em; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fLktadyn/8/