# Where "icon-remove-sign" has gone in Font Awesome 4.0.3

Tags: font-awesome

[Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) has recently changed icons notation from for example `icon-shield` to `fa-shield`.

But where has icon previously known as `icon-remove-sign` gone in the same time? I can't find it anywhere within [Font Awesome 4.0.3 icon list](http://fontawesome.io/icons/). Actually I don't see anything with `remove` in name or anything that would "accompany" (as opposite) icon (now called) `fa-check`.

In general, nearly every FA's "yes"-like icons have their counterparts ("no"-like icons). In general, you have variety of icon-sets for both "success" and "fail"-like situations. But this one is clearly missing.

Comment: This one maybe? http://fontawesome.io/icon/times/

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! It clearly seems, that I'm blind! :] I would never figure this out and I missed it while "visually" browsing new icon set. Please, consider reformulating your comment to fill-featured answer, so I can pick it and bring you some reps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font Awesome 4.0.0 Missing Icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554854/font-awesome-4-0-0-missing-icons)

Comment: thanks, here too.
It could have not been named any more stoooopidly than TIMES IMHO!

Comment: @RidIculous It's not that stupid. It is times (mathematical operation). However, any kind of alias to `delete` or `remove` seemed to be very obvious to everyone... except Font Awesome's author! :]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears the icon is now called `fa-times`: http://fontawesome.io/icon/times/.

At least as I understood the changes, the names should be more consistent with the actual icon shape, and "times" is the correct name for ×.

Comment: For others landing here, but looking for another icon, which name has changed, there's a great [Upgrading from 3.2.1 to 4](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4) guide, that deals with all the changed icons names.

Comment: "times" is just one of the interpretations (when you're talking about maths), and that too not very common one in web world. This is just eccentricity at its best.

Comment: Agree with Mrchief. I don't use this icon to write Math. I use it to **undo** or **close** or **remove**...Times..........I would never get why this is called _times_ without reading this post.

Answer (score 8):

The exact missing **icon-remove-sign** in Font Awesome 4.0 is **fa-times-circle**

```
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
```

and variation

```
<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
```

Comment: What is the reason behind adding an answer to already answered (over half year ago) question? BTW: the `circle` icons has nothing to do with this question. Original `delete`-like icon hasn't got any circle around it.

Comment: The question is "Where icon-remove-sign has gone"? The answer is, it hasn't gone anywhere, it is there, called "fa-times-circle" My reason was that the already answered question says "It appears.." and it didn't give me the correct answer which I found for others ;-)